# Where does RegexBuddy store its working data between uses?

Tags: regexbuddy

Ok, so I'm an idiot.

So I was working on a regex that took way to long to craft.  After perfecting it, I upgraded my work machine with a blazing fast hard drive and realized that I never saved the regex anywhere and simply used RegexBuddy's autosave to store it.  Dumb dumb dumb.

I sent a copy of the regex to a coworker but now he can't find it (or the record of our communication).  My best hope of finding the regex is to find it in RegexBuddy on the old hard drive.  RegexBuddy automatically saves whatever you were working on each time you close it.  I've done some preliminary searches to try to determine where it actually saves that working data but I'm having no success.

This question is the result of my dumb behavior but I thought it was a good chance to finally ask a question here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On my XP box, it was in the registry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JGsoft\RegexBuddy3\History
```

There were two REG_BINARY keys called **Action0** and **Action1** that had hex data containing my two regexes from the history.

[image: Screenshot of the Action registry key]

The test data that I was testing the regex against was here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\JGsoft\RegexBuddy 3
```

Comment: Your observations are correct.  The binary registry values are actually XML data.  The regex itself is human-readable between the XML tags.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS, of cause, but on Windows I would guess the application data directory. I can't remember the path on xp but on vista it's something like this:

C:\Users\ *user name* \AppData\

And then it would probably be here:

C:\Users\ *user name* \AppData\roaming